# How to translate 1980 US Census Place Code to post 1990 Place FIPS?

Tags: census, united-states, places

US Census PLaces are coded differently pre-1990 and post-1990, after the introduction of FIPS Code.

For instance, for Albertville, AL:

Pre-1990 : Place Code - PLACEA  : 0030

Post-1990: Place FIPS - PLACEFP : 00988

Is there an easy way to find a correspondance between these two codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the list of places from the 'vintage' census data: [us_places.txt](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/PREVGENZ/pl/us_places.txt)

The first column is the full census place code, which includes the state code as well as the place code. The second is the FIPS code, and the third is the name.

So for you're example:

> 010030 00988 Albertville city

01 is the state code for AL and 0030 is the old code for Albertville.