# FIPS Crosswalk for Census Places

Tags: census, united-states, fips

Where can I find a comprehensive crosswalk for FIPS codes at the Place level?

I need to match Census Places from different data sets spanning the period 1980-2010, where each data set is using FIPS code as a Place identifier.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102274/

Comment: @ChrisW It is related but not a duplicate since I am concerned with all changes in FIPS during the period 1980-2010, not only those that happened in 1990 (though most changes happened in 1990)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. 
For *my* benefit (and probably others, too): 

A **schema crosswalk** is a table that shows equivalent elements (or "fields") in more than one database schema. 
It maps the elements in one schema to the equivalent 
elements in another schema.

Crosswalk tables are often employed within or in parallel to enterprise systems, especially when multiple systems are interfaced or when the system includes legacy system data. In the context of Interfaces, they function as a sort of internal ETL mechanism.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_crosswalk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://mcdc2.missouri.edu/websas/geocorr2k.html

This service is provided by U Missouri, and it generates crosswalks like the one you're looking for.  I see census place geocodes as one of their options, and they cross to a variety of geographies.

Comment: Updated url: https://mcdc.missouri.edu/applications/geocorr2018.html