# Mapping older MSA definition to new codes

Tags: geoid, fips

I have an old dataset that uses msa codes that are four digits and go from 40 to 9999. I would like to match it with the current downloadable data from the Census which has fips codes that are 5 digits.
This seems like a straightforward task but I cannot find the answer.
I found a similar question at
[FIPS Crosswalk for Census Places](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142277/fips-crosswalk-for-census-places)
but the link provided there does not seem to have this older classification.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If this is open data then I think a better place for your question may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.